# Jobs - top tags order by score + badges

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

On jobs page top tags don't appear in order by score. For my profile in TOP 10 the following tags appear:

```
php mysql arrays laravel session
```

and it should be rather

```
php laravel ...
```

because for those 2 tags I have highest score.

I think it would be also nice to mark tags with badge if user has any. For example I have gold PHP badge for PHP tag, it would be nice to display here for potential employers that I have gold badge for this tag

Answer (score 1):

The whole reason we lumped things into Top 10% - Top 20% etc... is because the employers don't necessarily follow or understand the game (like badges).  Considering this, we need a level of granularity that both catches their attention, and doesn't distract them by making them learn a whole new thing in order to understand your CV.

I'll look to see what it takes to get the order as you specified, and I see why it would matter to *you*, but I don't think this will matter/resonate with employers.